# How to draw a Venn diagram in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I'd like to make this Venn diagram using TikZ (or otherwise at your discretion) based on this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55754/venn-diagrams-using-tikz)
[image]

so far I have this, which looks even worse than a powerpoint attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


 \def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
 \def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

  \colorlet{circle edge}{blue!50}
  \colorlet{circle area}{blue!20}

  \tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick}, outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

  \setlength{\parskip}{5mm}
\begin{figure}
\centering
% Set A and B

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \secondcircle;
    \draw[filled, even odd rule] \firstcircle
                                 \secondcircle node {Env.=242};
  \end{scope}
     \draw[outline] \firstcircle node {Pat=9}
               \secondcircle;
   \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$B - A$};


   \draw (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (4.5,2.5) node [text=black,above] {$\emptyset$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{figure}
```

[image]

I'd really appreciate a helping hand here as I do know from the posts that I've seen it should be quite straight forward.
Regards,

**EDIT:**

Is it possible to put the labels of the sets as they are in the picture?  The reason for this is that I have half a dozen Venn diagrams and I'm not sure colour coordination is the easiest to see.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest some modifications: instead of crowding the diagram with information, you can use colors and a legend to display some of the information; in my example code I used a simple tabular to build the legend; also notice that no additional libraries were used

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\radius{2cm}
\def\mycolorbox#1{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{2ex}{2ex}}}
\colorlet{colori}{blue!70}
\colorlet{colorii}{red!70}

\coordinate (ceni);
\coordinate[xshift=\radius] (cenii);

\draw[fill=colori,fill opacity=0.5] (ceni) circle (\radius);
\draw[fill=colorii,fill opacity=0.5] (cenii) circle (\radius);

\draw  ([xshift=-20pt,yshift=20pt]current bounding box.north west) 
  rectangle ([xshift=20pt,yshift=-20pt]current bounding box.south east);

\node[yshift=10pt] at (current bounding box.north) {Number of total episodes of case};

\node at ([xshift=\radius]current bounding box.east) 
{
\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{\,=\,}c@{}}
& Total & 431 \\
\mycolorbox{colori!50} & Env. & 189 \\
\mycolorbox{colorii!50} & Pat. & 422 \\
\end{tabular}
};

\node[xshift=-.5\radius] at (ceni) {$9$};
\node[xshift=.5\radius] at (cenii) {$242$};
\node[xshift=.9\radius] at (ceni) {$180$};
\node[xshift=10pt,yshift=10pt] at (current bounding box.south west) {$\emptyset$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After a comment, here's another variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\radius{2cm}
\def\mycolorbox#1{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{2ex}{2ex}}}
\colorlet{colori}{blue!70}
\colorlet{colorii}{red!70}

% some coordinates for the center of the circles
\coordinate (ceni);
\coordinate[xshift=\radius] (cenii);

% the circles
\draw (ceni) circle (\radius);
\draw (cenii) circle (\radius);

% the rectangle
\draw  ([xshift=-25pt,yshift=25pt]current bounding box.north west) 
  rectangle ([xshift=25pt,yshift=-25pt]current bounding box.south east);

%the labels
\node[xshift=-.5\radius] at (ceni) {$9$};
\node[xshift=.5\radius] at (cenii) {$242$};
\node[xshift=.9\radius] at (ceni) {$180$};
\node[xshift=-30pt,yshift=\radius+10pt] at (ceni) {Pat.${}=180$};
\node[xshift=30pt,yshift=\radius+10pt] at (cenii) {Env.${}=422$};
\node[xshift=10pt,yshift=10pt] at (current bounding box.south west) {$\emptyset$};
\node[yshift=10pt] at (current bounding box.north) {Number of total episodes of case};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(8,6)
    \psframe(8,6)
    \psset{fillstyle=solid,linecolor=cyan}
    \pscircle[fillcolor=cyan!50](5.25,3){2}
    \pscircle[fillcolor=white](2.75,3){2}
    \pscircle[fillstyle=none](5.25,3){2}
    \uput{5pt}[45](0,0){$\emptyset$}
    \rput[r](2.75,3){Pat=9}
    \rput[l](5.25,3){Env=242}
    \rput[b](4,5){$B-A$}
    \uput{2pt}[45](8,6){$H$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

I will go about it differently. Instead, I will draw the circle as nodes. Then, with the `fit` library, draw the borders. This way, you can write the labels relative to the named nodes.

### The Code

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101839/tikz-venn-diagramm
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\colorlet{circle edge}{blue!50}
\colorlet{circle area}{blue!20}
\tikzset{
     filled/.style={fill=circle area, thick,inner sep=0pt}, 
     outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick,inner sep=0pt}}

% The circles
\node (secondcircle) [circle,filled,text width=3cm] {};
\node (firstcircle) [circle,left=-1cm of secondcircle,outline,text width=3cm, fill=white] {};
\draw [outline] (secondcircle) circle (1.5cm);

% The labels
\node at ([xshift=-0.15cm]firstcircle) {$\mathrm{Pat=9}$};
\node at ([xshift=0.4cm]secondcircle) {$\mathrm{Env.=242}$};
\node at ($(firstcircle)!0.5!(secondcircle)$) {180};

% The rectangle and labels

\node (box) [fit=(firstcircle)(secondcircle), inner sep=1cm,draw,rounded corners] {};

\node at (box.north) [anchor=north] {$B-A$};
\node at (box.south west) [anchor=south west] {$\emptyset$};
\node at (box.south) [anchor=north] {432 total};
\node at (box.north east) [anchor=south west] {$H$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### The Output

[image]

BTW, if you have a lot of Venn Diagrams of two or three sets to draw, I advise you to try the package [`venndiagram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/venndiagram) by [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot).

### Update

I was not so sure at first what should be placed where, but the code below seems to be a more complete attempt.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5,convert={density=150}]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\colorlet{circle edge}{blue!50}
\colorlet{circle area}{blue!20}
\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, thick,inner sep=0pt}, outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick,inner sep=0pt}}
% The circles
\node (secondcircle) [circle,filled,text width=3cm] {};
\node (firstcircle) [circle,left=-1cm of secondcircle,outline,text width=3cm, fill=white] {};
\draw [outline] (secondcircle) circle (1.5cm);
% The labels
\node at ([xshift=-0.8cm]firstcircle.north) [anchor=south] {$\mathrm{Pat=422}$};
\node at ([xshift=0.8cm]secondcircle.north) [anchor=south] {$\mathrm{Env.=189}$};
\node at ($(firstcircle)!0.5!(secondcircle)$) {180};
\node at (firstcircle) {9};
\node at (secondcircle) {242};
% The rectangle and labels

\node (box) [fit=(firstcircle)(secondcircle), inner sep=1cm,draw, ultra thick,rounded corners] {};

\node [below=12pt of box.north] {$B-A$};
\node at (box.south west) [anchor=south west] {$\emptyset$};
\node at (box.south) [anchor=north] {431 total};
\node at (box.north east) [anchor=south west] {$H$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The coordinates with respect to the named nodes are called `anchors`. `center` is the only anchor present in all shapes. So if you name an anchor as `A`, then you can position another object, say, at `A.center`. Some more anchors are `north`, `south`, `east`, `west`, etc. You can see more of these in the `pgfmanual`. Just type and enter `texdoc pgf` in your terminal. In version 2.10, you can see some explanations starting from Section 16.5 on Positioning Nodes.

Answer (score 4):

It is common to use **ellispes** in Venn diagrams. For completion, I show here how draw a Venn diagram with **ellipses**.

There are many ways of drawing an ellipse in `tikz` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65018/how-to-draw-an-ellipse) for more details). Below there is a simple suggestion, using the `ellipse` option in `\draw`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node at (1,2) {Number of total episodes of case};

    \draw  (-2.5,-1.5)  rectangle (4.5,1.5);

    \draw[fill=blue!70,fill opacity=0.5] (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
    \draw[fill=red!70,fill opacity=0.5] (2,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
    
    \node at (-1,0) {$9$};
    \node at (1,0) {$242$};
    \node at (3,0) {$180$};
    \node at (-1,1.2) {Pat.${}=180$};
    \node at (3,1.2) {Env.${}=422$};
    \node at (-2.3,-1.3) {$\emptyset$};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I added the answer here because this is the most popular post in TeX.SE about Venn diagrams.